# passing VB.net array to javascript using ClientScript class

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, vb.net, clientscript

I am trying to use the ASP.net class ClientScript to pass an array to my aspx page. I have succesfully completed an earlier sample to do this (code sample below). But a new routine is not working. The difference is the ClientScript class.

Error states that "routeCoords is undefined"

my java code is...

```
function newTest() {
    var myArray = [ , ];
    var n = 0;

    var recCount = routeCoords.length / 15;

    for (var i = 0; i < recCount ; i++) {
        for (var s = 0; s < 15; s++) {

            myArray[i, s] = routeCoords[n];
            n++;

            alert(myArray[s], [i]);
        }
    }
}
```

vb.net to build array and register the script....

```
 ' arrylist
 For p = 0 To arryLst.Count - 1
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("routeCoords", arryLst(p))
 Next

Dim strScript As String = "newTest();"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "newTest", strScript.ToString, True)
```

the array is correctly populating in vb.net

this is the routine from the sample that is working...

VB.net code:

```
For s = 0 To arryLst.Count - 1
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("parmTypeAry", arryLst(s))
Next
```

JAVA code:

```
  // Create and Element Object of type "option"
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  //Add the option element to the select item
  listID.options.add(opt);
  //Reading Element From Array
  opt.text = parmTypeAry[s];
```

which populates a dropdownlist box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. It required an IF condition in the for loop to check for the array.

```
      for (i = 0; i < recCount; i++) {
      // Array of arrays builds out each record.
          if (!myArray[i])
              myArray[i] = []

          for (s = 0; s < 16; s++) {
              //  myArray[i] = new Array(14);

              myArray[i][s] = routeCoordsAry[n];
              n++;

              //  alert("i=" + i + " s=" + s + " Val: " + (myArray[i][s]));

          }
          // var u = 4;
          s = 0;

      }
```